# Date of the first day of the current month and the date of the 5 days earlier. MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I need a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN <1> AND <2>
```

Where `<1>` is the date of the first day of the month and `<2>` is the date of the day 5 days earlier. For example, if the current date is 2013-03-14, `<1>` should be 2013-03-01  and `<2>` 2013-03-09.

How can I do this?

Comment: What if the date is `2013-03-02`?

Comment: I need just return 0. And I'm doing this with PHP. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8962)**

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') d1,
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') d2,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') d3
```

Result:

```
|         D1 |         D2 |         D3 |
----------------------------------------
| 2013-03-14 | 2013-03-01 | 2013-03-09 |
```

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

This query probabbly don't gonna use INDEX because of formatting column with function `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')`

But if your column `date` datatype is `Datetime` When you can make your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') 
AND date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

Comment: You should be careful with `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN ...` because it can't use an index on date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 
        concat(extract(year_month FROM CURDATE()),"01") 
        AND 
        from_days(to_days(CURDATE())-5)
```